# how to query an online database from godot

Tags: httprequest, godot, gdscript

I have an online database which I need to access from inside Godot using GDScript. Is there a way of doing this, for example using HTTP requests in Godot? It cannot be a local database as it’s going to hold data about users.

I’ve tried using phpMyAdmin but as far as I’m aware there’s no way to communicate with it from inside Godot. I’ve also tried using other ways of storing data, for example Lootlocker and Firestore, but they aren’t right for my app. Thanks!

Comment: It's a little unclear where you're running in to trouble.  You will need to write an API/Web Service to read/write from your database and host that somewhere.  Then you can access the API using the HTTP request class in Godot.  Godot -> Requests resource from API -> API retrieves resource from database -> API returns resources to Godot -> Godot uses resource.

Comment: How would I go about writing an API? What language? Where do I host it? Thanks

Comment: Which online database do you use?

Comment: I started one on freesqldatabase.com

Comment: Retool is a good online database service with ability to expose queries via API. https://retool.com You might want to check it.